# Codename One - cn1lib files creation

Tags: codenameone

I have downloaded and installed some cn1lib files, like the BarScanner or DropBox libraries. I copied the files into the "lib" folder in NB and refreshed.

But now I wanted to try the Connectivity library and there is no "cn1lib" file. Only these 3 files:

[image]

I read on a blog post that we can create the files using NB, but there are no walkthru tutorials anywhere

**Question**

Can anyone explain how we should do it? (please don't skip steps. I am not a professional programmer)

Answer (score 0):

The cn1lib file should be in the dist directory of the library project since its the result of building the library project.

Comment: There is no "dist" directory, Shai. The only directories are 1-lib 2-native 3-nbproject 4-src/org/littlemonkey/connectivity.    I checked other Plugins, and some of them have the directory and cn1lib file. But others, like "Toast" don't have them

Comment: You can open the project in netbeans and just press build it will generate the binary. I created a pull request to the author with that binary https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/codenameone-connectivity/pull/1 so ideally he would have the binary online soon.

Comment: Just downloaded it. Thanks!

Comment: FYI if answers work they should be accepted/upvoted to improve our "answered" ratio.